# Невозможно отправить имя и пароль через selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import linecache

_Browser = webdriver.Firefox()
_Browser.get('http://www.webscantest.com/login.php')

_UserElement = _Browser.find_element_by_name('login')
_UserElement.send_keys('admin') 

for word in range(len(open('password.txt').readlines())):
    # try:
    _PasswordElement = _Browser.find_element_by_name('passwd') 
    password = linecache.getline('password.txt', word).replace('\n', '')
    _PasswordElement.send_keys(password)
    _PasswordElement.submit()
    _Browser.find_element_by_name('passwd').clear()

    print(password)
```

Получаю selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ./ancestor-or-self::form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import linecache

_Browser = webdriver.Firefox()
_Browser.get('http://www.webscantest.com/login.php')

_UserElement = _Browser.find_element_by_name('login')
_UserElement.send_keys('admin')

for word in range(len(open('password.txt').readlines())):
    # try:
    _PasswordElement = _Browser.find_element_by_name('passwd')
    password = linecache.getline('password.txt', word+1).replace('\n', '')
    _PasswordElement.send_keys(password)
    _PasswordElement.send_keys(u'\ue007')
    _Browser.find_element_by_name('passwd').clear()

    print(password)
```

Comment: linecache читает с 1 строчки, а не с 0, поэтому word +1

Comment: Как понять что пароль верний?